# Exporting documents from Ephesoft Comunity to Alfresco via CMIS Plugin

Tags: alfresco, cmis, opencmis, ephesoft

I'm trying to configure an Ephesoft Community Batch Class to export Documents to Alfresco by using CMIS.

I have followed [Ephesoft documentation](http://www.ephesoft.com/wiki/index.php?title=CMIS_Export_Plugin) with no luck.

If I carry out a scanning process, it fails on Export module. Log file says that there is a "conflict".

```
org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.commons.exceptions.CmisConstraintException: Conflict
```

I have tried with a customized DLF-Attribute-mapping and with an empty DLF-Attribute-mapping, without result.

Can somebody help me?

I have not reputation to add Ephesoft tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found out the problem.

Ephesoft Community (at least on Windows) uses a very old version of opencmis. Indeed it uses a 0.2 incubation version.

I don't know if the version of that library is directly related whit the error, but for avoid it, you need to configure Ephesoft to create a *cmis:document* as a major version.

It can be done, changing a parameter in *dcma_cmis* configuration file.

From

```
cmis.document_versioning_state=NONE
```

To

```
cmis.document_versioning_state=MAJOR
```

Maybe it helps someone.